# connecting to database on ec2 Virtual Machine from sql developer

Tags: amazon-ec2, oracle11g, virtual-machine, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4 to connect to databases . We are running an Oracle 11g on Amazon EC2 Virtual Machine (not RDS) and I can’t connect remotely. inside the Virtual Machine as local host it work fine.

how can I set up my Virtual Machine to be able to connect remotely via sql developer to database installed on that Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today and here is my configuration.
The Oracle 11g is installed on a RHEL EC2 instance and the SQL developer is installed on a Windows 2008 R2 Server instance.

We need to do these three things to fix the problem:

1) In the security group of the Amazon instances, add the inbound rules to allow connections to the Linux server. Notice that the Source IP address has to be the AWS private IP in the format of 172.31.0.0/16 instead of the public IP of 52.76.0.0/16.

2) Add the entry as below to your tnsnames.ora file:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ec2-52-76-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.us-west-2.compute.internal)
)
```

)

3) On the RHEL instance, only the ports of 22 (SSH) and 5904 (TightVNC) are opened now. We need to use the following command from ec2-user account to punch a hole in the firewall to open the port of 1521 which is used by Oracle database service.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
```